# Routing in Rails has problems with Controller/action/id route

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, routes

In my Rails 4 application I create pages through a PagesController to form a menu. The menu has links to redirect_to index action of the appropriate controller. Columns for that Page model are :id, :title, :access_level, :html (actually refers to the controller), :icon

Example data is: 5, Employees, 3, employees, users

NOTE: Irrelevant parts of code such as "resources :employees" are not visible!

Routes file:

```
resources :pages
resources :access
```

PagesController:

```
def show
  @pages = Page.find(params[:id])
  redirect_to controller: "#{@page.html}", action: "index"
end
```

Block to generate links

```
<% @pages = Page.all %>
<% @pages.each do |page| %>
<li>
    <%= link_to({ controller: "pages", action: "show", id: "#{page.id}" }) do %><i class="fa fa-<%= page.icon %> fa-fw"></i> <%= page.title %>
    <% end %>
</li>
<% end %>
```

HTML Generated link_to based on the example:

```
<a href="/pages/5"><i class="fa fa-users fa-fw"></i> Employees</a>
```

Everything works fine except when I try to implement a basic login system but get the following error:

```
ActionController::UrlGenerationError in Access#index
Showing C:/Users/Samsung/Documents/rails/AjansTakip/app/views/access/index.html.erb where line #9 raised:

No route matches {:action=>"attempt_login", :controller=>"access"}
```

Index.html.erb Line 9 of Access View

```
<%= form_for :access, url: {action: "attempt_login"} do |f| %>
```

AccessController (:id_number is short for identification_number and has no relation to :id)

```
def attempt_login
    if params[:id_number].present? && params[:password].present?
        found_user = Employee.where(id_number: params[:id_number]).first
        if found_user
            authorized_user = found_user.authenticate(params[:password])
        end
    end
    if authorized_user
        redirect_to controller: 'pages', action: 'index'
    else
        redirect_to action: 'login'
    end
  end
```

I am following Lynda Rails 4 Essential Training and I am unable to pass the first part of the implementation of the basic login system therefore please do not comment on any part of coding other than routing since I am trying to learn it on my own.

As far as solutions I tried this one which works to pass the error to bump into another one

```
get 'access/attempt_login', to: 'access#attempt_login'
```

but I am pretty sure there is a better way of handling these kind of situations. 
I get another error when I submit the form via post on index.html.erb:

```
No route matches [POST] "/access/attempt_login"
```

I think the problem arises because of the default routing which is :controller(/:id(/:action)) and that the controller expects an :id before the :action. I see no point in routing "get" for all kind of actions that do not require an :id.

Another solution that I used was to change the default routing to ":controller(/:action(/:id))" but this causes even more problems than it solves (we might even say it does not solve anything at all). Even the links in the menu break because link_to :action "show" does not get parsed as href="pages/show/5". I also tried generating links as link_to({ controller: "pages", action: "show", id: "**show/**#{page.id}" }) but this is nowhere as practical and dynamic as I would want to be.

Please point me in the right direction. I am also willing to change how Paging works with the PagesController, I could not think of a better way of storing pages in a database and redirecting them all in one place.

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yeah don't use the default controller stuff, that's old school. Instead, give this a try:

Delete the get line:

```
get 'access#attempt_login', to: 'access#attempt_login'
```

Now, since you want it on a collection of the resource, try this:

```
resources :access do
  collection do
    get :attempt_login
  end
end
```

Then in your form:

```
 <%= form_tag attempt_login_access_path, method: :get do |f| %>
```

I use form_tag when it comes to urls that aren't for create or update actions. Form_for is good when you have a model present. The method get is also important, as forms default to post. You may need to double check that route path:

```
bundle exec rake routes | grep attempt
```

And ensure the method is right.

Comment: Did as you suggested, the correct path was attempt_login_access_index_path and with that I was able to solve the problem. Would you mind If I ask you to dissect "attempt_login_access_index_path" and explain why "index" is in there? Is it the name of the view? Why did it not generate a path like you foresaw?

Thanks.

Comment: Good question on the index being there. To explain it better, when you add a collection block, any methods you put in there will map to that controller, to that action. So we're doing a get request to the attempt_login action. If you use `member` instead of `collection`, it does the same thing, but expects an id: `/access/:id/attemp_login`, so you can do extra methods on singular resources. I do a similar setup though, and i do not get the index thing :). If you want to post your full routes file, i can try to figure it out.

Comment: At the time this was experienced the routes file only had simple non-nested resources such as resources :employees, :projects etc. Thanks for your effort :)